# Loading GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I do `php artisan config:cache` as recommended in the official documentation for speed improvement.

As you may know, this command makes the .env file variables directly inaccessibles (you can test it with `php artisan tinker`), and for that reason all the calls to `env()` and `getenv()` function must be replaced by `config()` in the code, except for the files in the config folder. After executing this command, calls like `env('APP_ENV')` return NULL.

In my project, I'm connecting to Google Cloud using the [google-auth-library-php](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php). Unfortunately, in the CredentialsLoader.php file there is a call to the function `getenv(self::ENV_VAR)` that attempts to get the path of the Google credentials file. As I run the command `php artisan config:cache`, the path can't be read from the .env file and the connection cannot be completed.

I can see 3 ways to continue:

1. Forget about running `php artisan config:cache`.
2. Ask here if somebody knows how to specify the path of the Google credentials file as a parameter of any function of the package.
3. (Forgive me, God) Correct the CredentialsLoader.php file (`getenv()` to `config()`), run the command and track this file in the repository, then this change will propagate to every team member when they pull.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's `CredentialsLoader::fromEnv` that loads from env. It makes sense to use another method on CredentialsLoader, or create the credentials thingie manually using settings in your config.

Comment: Hi! has been 3 years now... :) What was your solution?

Comment: Well actually I did it with a particular configuration... Nignx + php with fastcgi. I will answer because maybe can be of any help if in the future someone will visit this question again

Answer (score 1):

For those who still encounter this error, you can specify the file using `keyFile` index in the first parameter:

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
   'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true),
]);
```

Or you can specify the .json file directly to config using `keyFilePath` index

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
   'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/json/CompanyDataStorage-foobarbaz.json',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very old question but maybe it can be useful for someone coming for the same problem even in the newer versions of Laravel.
Basically I don't have a solution that works for all the possible environments, but it gives the idea.
My environment runs `php7.4-fpm` with `NGINX`.
If you are using the same environment, you will have a `location` directives for your php files.
Nginx can set FastCGI parameters with `fastcgi_param` and you will have probably used it with `SCRIPT_FILENAME` etc..
You can can then add

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    [...]
    fastcgi_param GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/absolute/path/to/keyfile.json";
}
```

Then just reload Nginx (ex. for Ubuntu 20.04, `sudo systemctl reload nginx`).

For Apache the same idea would probably work with `SetEnv` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv